# Cygwin bash calls adb with awk does not see dollar sign $

Tags: awk, cygwin, adb

I am running a bash script under windows cygwin.

Important note:

I run the bash script from a command.exe window like:

bash.exe myscript.sh

The script will do an adb shell and ps/awk/kill a process.  The android is rooted.  The script below works except for the awk part.  It seems that something about running this under window makes the dollar sign in $2 invalid.  So the last awk part does not work.  Help!

```
#!/bin/bash     -x      
C:/scripts/adb.exe shell << EOF
su
ls
ps  | grep "myapp" | echo  awk '{print $2}'
EOF
```

The output I get from this script:

```
# awk {print }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this

```
ps  | grep "myapp" | awk '{print $2}'
```

`awk` utility takes input from a pipe or from a file. When you do `echo` followed by command, shell interprets it as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

When using a here-file, all $var are evalutated by the shell as part of processing.

I think you can fix this, just by escaping any '$'s (that are for variables or shell parms, et), with the '' char, i.e. '$2', and for your case it would be

**Edit:** Your code has an extra word in it, 'echo', I've removed that from the solutions below.

```
#!/bin/bash     -x      
C:/scripts/adb.exe shell << EOF
su
ls
ps  | grep "myapp" | awk '{print \$2}'
EOF
```

Or you can 'quote' the whole here-file by quoting the EOF, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash     -x      
C:/scripts/adb.exe shell <<'EOF'
su
ls
ps  | grep "myapp" | awk '{print $2}'
EOF
```

Note that the closing EOF should **not** be quoted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the difference in the implementation. +1 for an excellent walk-thru.

Comment: Unfortunatly the slash or quoting the EOF did not work.  In both cases the output is now: # awk {print $2}

Comment: @user848106 : Doah, note your code `echo awk '{print $2}'`! It's working as designed ;-). Remove the echo and you should be getting procesing of the pipestream. Good luck